# How to make the inherited class's constructor run after a class's constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have 2 classes: `Base` and `Main`. When I run the `Main`'s constructor, I want to run some code **BEFORE** the `Base`'s constructor runs. In `java`, it's easy, you write some code then use `super`. Is there a way to achive the same result using `C#`?

```
class Base
{
    public string myString = "Hi";
    public Base(string str)
    {
        myString += str;
    }
}

class Main : Base
{
    public Main() : base(" world")
    {
        base.myString = "Hello";
    }
}

class Program
{
    Console.WriteLine(new Main().myString);
}
```

I expect the output to be `Hello world`, but it's only `Hello`, because the `Main`'s constructor run after the `Base`'s constructor.

Comment: No there's no way to change the ordering, you will need another solution. However, I've never once needed anything like this, it's really peculiar.

Comment: maybe composition would be better in this case

Comment: No, there is no easy way. Use the factory pattern to construct and then call a "PostInitialize" or similar method on the instance before returning it from the factory method.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't simple way.
Solution: declare `protected abstract void PreInitialization()` method and call it ASAP in the `Base`'s ctor. Then provide appropriate implementation at the `Main` level. That's the closest to your requirement.

Other (better) solution: provide a standalone `Factory<T> where T : Base` with `T Make(Action preInitializationAction);`. Then you decide when to create object and when to invoke provided callback; but still, there might be issues with accessing `T`'s fields: your callback won't be able to access them since the object does not exist yet.

P.S. Seems like you've misdesigned something. Such a solution is quite unreliable and does not follow practicies known to be good.

Comment: Calling a virtual method in a constructor is a recipe for problems, as it will execute in the most overridden version of the method, before the constructor for the type that defined that method has executed. It is **not** recommended.

Comment: I agree. That's why I appended "P.S." section at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible and if it were, you wouldn't be able to do anything with the base class because it would still be null until the constructor runs. What you can do is leaving the constructor empty and creating a void 'Construct' and calling it from the end of Main's constructor, this way you will be able to change myString because the object exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal way to achieve this by any language construction. What comes up in mind is to simulate this behavior with using a constructor in base class which would accept some action to execute first:

```
class Base
{
    public string myString = "Hi";
    public Base(string str)
    {
        myString += str;
    }

    public Base(string str, Action<Base> runFirts)
    {
        runFirts?.Invoke(this);
        myString += str;
    }
}

class Main : Base
{
    public Main() : base(
        "world",
        instance => { instance.myString = "Hello"; })
    {
    }
}
```

Anyway nor sure why you need it but please note that such implementation requirements may indicate a problem with design.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**

**It's just a demonstration. Do not use it in production.**

You ask for something unnatural for c#. And I like it. Prepare to watch some magic.
But let's start with patching the initial code. First, let's change Main class name to Derived.
It is also known the field inline initialization is a sintactic sugar. Compiler puts initialization to all constructors. So will we. And let's add null coalescing. It will not affect the result at first, but will be a gerat help next.
And we also should put our classes into a separate class library (e.g. ClassLibrary).
So we have:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Base
    {
        public string myString;

        public Base(string str)
        {
            myString = myString ?? "Hi";
            myString += str;
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived() : base(" world")
        {
            base.myString = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Then compile the library, create a console application and add a reference to the compiled dll via Add Reference... -> Browse -> Browse...
Add code like yours:

```
using System;
using ClassLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Derived().myString);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is just
`Hello`
as in your case.

Now open the dll with ildasm and dump it (File -> Dump, Dump IL Code checked) into ClassLibrary.il and exit ildasm. Open ClassLibrary.il with any text editor and find Derived class constructor. It starts with `.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ClassLibrary.Derived` and contains:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldstr      " world"
IL_0006:  call       instance void ClassLibrary.Base::.ctor(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  nop
IL_000d:  ldarg.0
IL_000e:  ldstr      "Hello"
IL_0013:  stfld      string ClassLibrary.Base::myString
IL_0018:  ret
```

Change it to (in IL one calls base class constructor anywhere manually):

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello"
IL_0006:  stfld      string ClassLibrary.Base::myString
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  nop
IL_000d:  ldarg.0
IL_000e:  ldstr      " world"
IL_0013:  call       instance void ClassLibrary.Base::.ctor(string)
IL_0018:  ret
```

Then save ClassLibrary.il and from command prompt run:

```
"%ILASM_LOCATION%\ilasm.exe" "%ClassLibrary.il_LOCATION%\ClassLibrary.il" /dll /output:"%ClassLibrary.dll_LOCATION%\ClassLibrary.dll"
```

Run the console application again and see:
`Hello world`

Opened with ILSpy Derived class looks:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        myString = "Hello";
        base..ctor(" world");
    }
}
```

But put to ClassLibrary project it gives:

> Error  CS1001  Identifier expected...
>
> Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'str' of 'Base.Base(string)'...
>
> Error  CS0117  'Base' does not contain a definition for ''...

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**

**It's just a demonstration. Do not use it in production.**

Modify `Base` a bit for technical reasons.

```
class Base
{
    public string myString;

    protected Base(object obj) { }

    public Base(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tTracing: ctor 'Base(string)' called");
        myString = myString ?? "Hi";
        myString += str;
    }
}
```

Modify `Main`.

```
class Main : Base
{
    private Action<string> ctor;

    private Action<string> @base =>
        ctor ?? (ctor = (Action<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), this as Base, ".ctor"));

    public Main() : base(new object())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tTracing: ctor 'Main()' called");
        myString = "Hello";
        @base(" world");
    }
}
```

Now test it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Base(" from base").myString);
        Console.WriteLine(new Main().myString);
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
        Tracing: ctor 'Base(string)' called
Hi from base
        Tracing: ctor 'Main()' called
        Tracing: ctor 'Base(string)' called
Hello world
```